# Converting linq result set to data table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

```
var query = (from row in playerSpotAndValue.AsEnumerable()
             where !row.Field<string>("RunningTotal").Contains("/")
             group row by row.Field<UInt16>("SpotID") into spotID
             orderby spotID.Key
             select new
             {
                 SpotID = spotID.Key,
                 HandTotal= spotID.Max(p => Convert.ToUInt16(p.Field<string>("RunningTotal"))),
                 RowsCount = spotID.Count()
             });
```

How to use CopyToDataTable in this query so that i can query like this

```
query.CopyToDataTable().Rows[0]["HandTotal"].ToString();
```

Comment: As an aside, you could achieve the query you want by just doing query.First().HandTotal.ToString() and it will save you some memory and time.

Comment: Have you tried to achieve the same using [Expression-based Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)?

Comment: @kmp: please put this as your answer , I'll accept it. thanks

Comment: @Mohan - I would do that (I would love the reputation points) but your question is asking how to put the query into a data table and a bunch of other people have been kind enough to answer your question.  I was giving you an alternative idea which is not really an answer to what you asked so I think it would be really unfair on the others, who answered your question in good faith, if I were to put it as an answer and you were to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use the following [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx):

```
public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : DataRow
```

---

But first you need to have `IEnumerable<DataRow>` but not of anonymous types.

Your table should have the columns you want to populate, then use `DateTable.NewRow()` method

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `dtDealerTotal`(orgininally referenced in your question) is the table in which you want to find the rows with `SpotID` from your query and you want to add the `HandTotal` result as `DataColumn`:

```
DataTable result = dtDealerTotal.Clone();
result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("HandTotal", typeof(UInt16)));
var dealers = dtDealerTotal.AsEnumerable();
foreach (var x in query)
{
    foreach (var d in dealers.Where(dr => dr.Field<UInt16>("SpotID") == x.SpotID))
    {
        var fields = d.ItemArray;
        fields.Concat(new Object[] { x.HandTotal });
        result.Rows.Add(fields);
    }
}
```

**Note**: You can only use `CopyToDataTable` on existing DataRows, not on anonymous types. So you either need to select these rows first to copy them into a new `DataTable` or (when the schema is different like here, since you want to add `HandTotal`) you need to create a new `DataTable` manually, which is what i did.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you can achieve, what you want .

Your LINQ query, and here is a function that return DataTable:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(DataContext ctx, object query) // ctx is your data context, & query is your linq query 
{
    IDbCommand cmd;

    try
    {
        cmd = ctx.GetCommand(query as IQueryable);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not connect database");
    }

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = (SqlCommand)cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();

    }
    catch
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        throw new Exception("Could not connect database");
    }

    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        throw new Exception("Query Parsing Error");
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Don't copy-paste from the answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
query.First().HandTotal.ToString()
```

This way I can find hand total in very first row and therefore I need not put my linq query result set in data table. I would like to say thank to Mr. kmp.